# Can't run react-native example in windows

Tags: windows, react-native

I'm trying to run the getting started [example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#testing-your-react-native-installation) in windows for android but after running

```
react-native run-android
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'isNative'
   at CallSiteToString (X:\code\react_native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:195:3)
   at Anonymous function (X:\code\react_native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:304:5)
   at Array.prototype.map (native code)
   at prepareStackTrace (X:\code\react_native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:303:3)
   at stackGetter (Unknown script code:208:9)
   at socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:303:3)
   at emitOne (events.js:96:5)
   at emit (events.js:188:7)
   at emitErrorNT (net.js:1265:3)
   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have a problem with your code ! what is 'isNative' in your code ?
it's better to to copy your code and paste it here.

Comment: I'm using react-native init to create the project. I haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In case anyone else faces this problem it seems I had both a regular node installation and a node (chakra) installation and the chakra one was causing problems with react-native. After uninstalling node(chakra), react-native runs fine.